# How to change the Imagerecource when Button is clicked

Tags: android, if-statement, imageview, onclicklistener

I want to click on an ImageView and when a certain amount of clickes is reached, I want the Imageview to change the image.
This is my code but I dont know where the problem is.
There is no error or something.
The Picture just doesnt change
Can you guys help me please.
Thanks

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private ImageView megg;
int counter = 0;
int readhighscore;
private TextView mnumber;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mnumber = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.number);
    mnumber.setText(Integer.toString(readhighscore));
    megg = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.egg);
    megg.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            counter++;
            readhighscore = counter;
            mnumber.setText(Integer.toString(readhighscore));

        }

    });

    if (counter == 10){
        ImageView megg = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.egg);
        megg.setImageResource(R.drawable.egg100);

    }

    if (counter == 100){
        ImageView megg = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.egg);
        megg.setImageResource(R.drawable.egg100);

    }
    if (counter == 500){
        ImageView megg = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.egg);
        megg.setImageResource(R.drawable.egg500);

    }


    SharedPreferences prefs = this.getSharedPreferences("myPrefsKey", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    counter = prefs.getInt("highscore", readhighscore);


}
@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();

    SharedPreferences prefs = this.getSharedPreferences("myPrefsKey", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
    editor.putInt("highscore", readhighscore);

    editor.commit();

}
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();SharedPreferences prefs = this.getSharedPreferences("myPrefsKey", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    counter = prefs.getInt("highscore", readhighscore);
    readhighscore = counter;
    mnumber.setText(Integer.toString(readhighscore));
}
}
```

Comment: Have you confirmed the counter is actually getting incremented?  Would need to see a little more code such as where the onClick listener is being attached to and where the counter is declared.  Your setImageResource(..) is fine, but I assume is not being called.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put the flow statements inside the onClick method. Currently, `If statements` are outside of the `OnClickListener` and hence it will not get called on every click and you want to perform this check on every click.

```
 @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        counter++;
if (counter == 10){
    ImageView megg = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.egg);
    megg.setImageResource(R.drawable.egg100);

}

if (counter == 100){
    ImageView megg = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.egg);
    megg.setImageResource(R.drawable.egg100);

}
if (counter == 500){
    ImageView megg = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.egg);
    megg.setImageResource(R.drawable.egg500);

}


    }

});
```